# Make Datetimepicker display unchanged value till picking a date in the dropdown calendar C#

Tags: datetimepicker

When using a default winform DateTimePicker, if you click on dropdown, then you can scroll(or page) the calendar by mouse or arrow keys and the displayed date/time value is changed accordingly. Is there a way to keep the displayed value not impacted ,i.e., seemingly null (as a space) if backend value is null or a fixed value from the backend database, until you truly pick a value from the calendar to override it?

Sometimes customers want to view the DateTimePicker value constantly from backend as a reference while choosing a new value from the calendar. I am thinking of combining a textbox together with a datetimepicker to achieve this behavior but hasn't yet drawn solid conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing around with this, and I believe you want to use the Custom Format option.  You may need to play around with this a little, but basically, I added a property (string) named "ChosenDate"... I then assigned it to the "CustomFormat" property of datetimepicker1, then reset it on closeup.  Play around with this and see if you can get it to do what you want...

Property

```
private string _dttime;

public string ChosenDate
{
    get { return _dttime; }
    set { _dttime = value; }
}
```

In initialization function...

```
ChosenDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = ChosenDate;
dateTimePicker1.CloseUp += dateTimePicker1_CloseUp;
```

handler function

```
void dateTimePicker1_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChosenDate = (sender as DateTimePicker).Value.ToShortDateString();
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = ChosenDate;
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  If you don't mind marking as solution, I would appreciate it.